# Updating the emacs style Time Stamp comments in vim

Tags: vim, emacs, timestamp

How can I implement this [emacs auto time stamp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Time-Stamps.html) in vim?

I have the following string at the top of a file:

```
// Time-stamp: <>
```

Here `//` are comment characters.

What do I need to do so that on saving the file, gvim auto updates that time stamp field to:

```
// Time-stamp: <DATE TIME USER>
```

On every subsequent save, the date, time, user must be updated.

It would be useful to have this implemented in vim so that both emacs and vim users can auto update the time stamp on saving files.

Comment: Why would you put a timestamp *in* your file when your filesystem already saves the creation and modification dates and your VCS keeps even more information?

Comment: It's useful to have a quick glance at when you or someone else modified the file. I use emacs and I rarely have to do "ls -la" to review and open files. Also the way my company's version control system works, I won't be able to tell if the file was modified by me or someone else by a simple "ls -la". The VCS stores checkins to a central cache and symbolically links to that cache. So when anyone updates the file, I just see the time stamp update and my username. Also I wanted the in-file time stamp feature to work for emacs as well as vim users alike.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to my `.vimrc` worked:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.* :%s/^\s*\(\/\/\|#\|%\|"\)\s\+Time-stamp:\s\+<\zs.*/\=strftime('%Y-%m-%d') . ' ' . strftime('%H:%M:%S') . ' ' . $USER . '>'/e
```

Comment: 1.) BufWritePost is executed after the write. It might be more useful to update the buffer before writing it to disk. The right event is [BufWrite or BufWritePre](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWrite). 2.) if you add an additional `\+` after the regular expression starting a comment, the time stamps gets updated, if the line starts with a headline comment.

Answer (score 1):

For a more advanced solution, have a look at my [AutoAdapt plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4654); it offers configurable replacements, and doesn't clobber the last search pattern or cursor position, which are problems that your simplistic solution suffers from.